# Python: Parse Text file with '|' to MySql table

Tags: python, parsing, extract, text-files

I have a text file which has the following structure:

```
341|18 Hello world|20090225230048AAnhStI|90|$0.30|10|289|2|2|2|Is that foo or 
boo bar?  18 |Is it boo foo and foo bar?|    |I beleive its foo.|396545163|foo 
& bar>foo & boo
```

Basically each data element is separated by `|`. I am planning on using a Python script to parse this data and write it to a table. Based on the information I gathered from internet I can't take advantage of Python's tab separated or comma separated options to import such a file into a MySql data base.

- Am I wrong?
- If so, what would be the best option for doing such a thing?

My idea is to create a table and extract only the element that I want to extract from the above string to store it in each column. But, I also would like to know how to track what to extract. Do I use a counter while I iterating over each element..?

I thought I'd ask these question before I proceed.

My current intuition is to do the following:

```
import sys

file = open('datafile.txt')
for line in file:
    print line.strip().split('|')
```

Comment: If you don't want to do heavy manipulation, you can use **LOAD DATA INFILE** to load the data to a table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I think you shouold have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html, it has a lot of power. It should be able to use the pipe as delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is fine.  You can also use the [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv
with open('datafile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|'):
        ...
```

Comment: I just tried the code that you put but didn't really work. thanks for the csv.reader link..

Comment: fixed a bug in the code... Also I still have the question of how can I just get only the fields that I want want to avoid extracting ignore from following string.. hello|world|ignore|101 thanks..